# Operator norm and orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$,$B$ be two positive semidefinite symmetric matrices on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the same eigenvectors. Let $P$ be an orthogonal projection. Does it hold that

$$
\|APB\| \leq \|AB\|,
$$

where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the operator norm. If $P$ was on the left or right we would directly have $\|ABP\| \leq \|AB\|\|P\| \leq \|AB\|$. However here, trying to show it from the definition of the operator norm does not help me to conclude as for all $x$, we have

$$
\|APBx\|^2 = x^{\top}BPA^2PBx, 
$$

and I don't know how to drop $P$ from this expression.

Does it still hold if we drop the assumption that $A$,$B$ share the same eigenvectors?

Answer (score 2):

No. Counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{1\\ &0},\quad
P=\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}},\quad
B=\pmatrix{0\\ &1}.
$$
In this case $\|APB\|=\frac{1}{2}>0=\|AB\|$.